# PHP Datetime update time leaving date untouched

Tags: php, datetime

I have a datetime object in PHP created from a timestamp.
I wish to set the time of the datetime to midday whilst leaving the date untouched. Will setTime work to update or will it overwrite my current time from the timestamp?

```
$data['users'][$user]['install'] = new \DateTime();
$data['users'][$user]['install']->setTimestamp(min($data['users'][$user]['sessions']));
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You know, there's a thing called __manual__ http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.settime.php

Comment: You should attempt to work on the problem yourself and post the code you come up with.

Comment: @u_mulder Will settime only effect the part I supply?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$data['users'][$user]['install']->setTime(12, 0);
```

Comment: I need to update an existing DateTime, not create a new one.

Comment: @MattCowley can you show the code you have already? And you could call this method on the old DateTime

Comment: Thank you, worked perfectly. I assumed setTime would overwrite my current time.

Comment: @MattCowley no thanks! I would greatly appreciate it if you accept my answer as the solution

Comment: will do when stackoverflow lets me.